How to get the browser name in .NET version 8 Aspire?
I want to capture the browser name of the user who is filling the form.
I tried using HttpContextAccessor but couldn't fetch User-Agent.
How to solve this issue?
Here is the method I have used:
public string GetBrowserDetails()
{
    var browserDetails = string.Empty;
    HttpRequest request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

    if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("User-Agent"))
    {
        var userAgent = request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        // Log or debug the userAgent value to ensure it is not empty
        Console.WriteLine($"User-Agent: {userAgent}");

        var browser = string.Empty;
        var version = string.Empty;

        if (Regex.IsMatch(userAgent, @"Edge\/\d+"))
        {
            browser = "Edge";
            version = Regex.Match(userAgent, @"Edge\/(\d+\.\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(userAgent, @"Edg\/\d+"))
        {
            browser = "Edge";
            version = Regex.Match(userAgent, @"Edg\/(\d+\.\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            browser = "Unknown";
            version = "Unknown";
        }

        browserDetails = $"Browser: {browser} Version: {version}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User-Agent header not found");
    }

    return browserDetails;
}

I couldn't enter into his if condition as User-Agent is returned empty. How to resolve this issue? If anyone knows how to fetch the browser information any other way, please let me know.

Aspire isn't a different kind of web stack and probably isn't even relevant. Your web app or service is still a Web API, MVC, Razor or Blazor web app. You get the request information the same way you always did

Which stack are you actually using and where is GetBrowserDetails used? There's no HTTP context in a background service for example. I suspect this is a duplicate of other ASP.NET Core questions

You do know that the User-Agent header is useless for that now, right?

Hi @Eswar Satish Karella, pls F12 in your browser and check the Network request if it sends the user-agent header. Then also debug your code to check the httpcontext if it contains value.

Are you sure that httpContextAccessor is not null?
Here is the code that you should Inject the IHttpContextAccessor :
public class BrowserDetector
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BrowserDetector(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetBrowserDetails()
    {
        var browserDetails = string.Empty;
        HttpRequest request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("User-Agent"))
        {
            var userAgent = request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"User-Agent: {userAgent}");

            var browserPatterns = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Edge", @"Edge\/(\d+\.\d+)" },
                { "Edge (Chromium)", @"Edg\/(\d+\.\d+)" },
                { "Chrome", @"Chrome\/(\d+\.\d+)" },
                { "Firefox", @"Firefox\/(\d+\.\d+)" },
                { "Safari", @"Version\/(\d+\.\d+).*Safari" },
                { "Opera", @"OPR\/(\d+\.\d+)" },
                { "Internet Explorer", @"Trident\/\d+.*rv:(\d+\.\d+)" }
            };

            string browser = "Unknown";
            string version = "Unknown";

            foreach (var pattern in browserPatterns)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(userAgent, pattern.Value);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    browser = pattern.Key;
                    version = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            browserDetails = $"Browser: {browser} Version: {version}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User-Agent header not found");
        }

        return browserDetails;
    }
}

Register the service in program.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // other service configurations
}

